# Why deleting an item listview does not delete its checkbox?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a listview with checkboxes (multiple). I have implemented a deletion of an element in the listview with a simple:

```
              adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(item));
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

It works, except for the fact that the checkboxes status are messed up: the listview goes up filling the deleted guy as it should, but the ckeckboxes stay in the same state. In other words, if the list is:

```
a   on
b   off
c   on
d   off
e   on
```

and you delete the second, you get:

```
a   on
c   off
d   on
e   off
```

It's like I deleted the textview but not the checkbox of my listview.... 
Have you seen this happening before? Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you overriding getView(), or ViewBinder?

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah: No, I'm not touching the adapter. I just want to delete one item.

Comment: I "solved" the issue in a dirty way: got the checked states, delete element, restore checked states.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Android tends to be illogical sometimes, at least to what a normal human developer expects.

Do it like this. The magic is in checkedItemPositions.Clear(). This was originally C# MonoDroid code, I hope I translated it correctly back to Java.

```
// Delete the checked items
SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
int itemCount = list.getCount();
for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (checkedItemPositions.get(i)) {
        listAdapter.remove(data[i]);
        data.removeAt(i);
    }
}
checkedItemPositions.clear();
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```